# Automatically replace the "enter image description here" when the post is saved

Tags: feature-request

When users attach a screenshot to a post, the system automatically adds the text "enter image description here" as tooltip that is associated to the image.
Once the post is saved, it can be replaced with a generic and shorter text, such as "screenshot." If the OP didn't change the default text, it means he doesn't care of the tooltip, and the default text doesn't have anymore the function to remember to the OP to enter a description for the image.

Comment: I would rather it changed to something like, "Author hates blind people".

Answer (score 6):

I do not think this is a good idea. It does not make the image any more accessible.

I have started a thread asking people to fill in image descriptions of old images:

[Call to action: fill in image descriptions](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5270/call-to-action-fill-in-image-descriptions)