# Call to action: fill in image descriptions

Tags: support, images

We had [a request](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1515/automatically-replace-the-enter-image-description-here-when-the-post-is-saved) a couple of years ago to replace "enter image decription here" with some sort of generic text. I think this is a bad idea, as it doesn't add anything. Shog's comment on the proposal essentially articulates how I feel:

> I would rather it changed to something like, "Author hates blind people".

So our only other option is to enter useful descriptions by hand.

[This Google search](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=site%3Aenglish.stackexchange.com+%22enter+image+description+here%22&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-GB:official&client=firefox-a&channel=sb&gfe_rd=cr&ei=Y-o8VJr_O8-q8wfC_oKACw) shows which posts are still in need of help.

I will make a list of posts that still require fixing, and we can remove them from the list as we go. Feel free to add any that you find yourself.

You don't have to write like Shakespeare or Nabokov, just something that makes it clear what the picture is of.

Obviously this is a big task, but each picture adequately described is a little victory!

If you're interested in tips on how best to fill out an alt text, [this site](http://webaim.org/techniques/alttext/) has some ideas.

Comment: Thanks for doing this, Matt!

Comment: So, how long before Google updates its search and we can get a new batch to edit? Right now, the search link returns a bunch of questions that have already been edited.

Comment: I'll go through the search and find some more candidates. Thanks for you help, @Marthaª.

Comment: What to do about Google nGram plots?

Comment: @200_success: I've been doing my best to describe them. "Phrase A (in red) has its first peak in 1850, then it gradually increases to its highest peak in 1900, after which it gradually declines to below its 1850 peak by 1990. Phrase B (in blue) first shows up in 1920 and lags behind Phrase A until around 1950. There are crossover points in 1960 and 1975, but after that, Phrase B starts outstripping Phrase A, and by 1990 it rises above Phrase A's highest peak." Or some such.

Comment: color is irrelevant.

Comment: Please look at [this link regarding alt text](http://webaim.org/techniques/alttext/). It appears I've been doing it ... overkill. The images should not have to be overly descriptive. In fact, the public facing written context of the post should be adequately describing the image anyway. If that happens, the correct answer for non-link images could be alt="", with the appropriate text visible.

Comment: @SrJoven colour *might* be irrelevant, I could imagine that severely short sighted people might utilize these  screen readers too. But I'm not sure, never having seen these devices myself. No doubt that in the US these are common tools. "Overkill" is exactly wanted to say in my post, an overload of information and detail, which becomes almost counter productive. And then what about Ngrams? How would you describe similar charts where results spike suddenly or slowly curve upwards/downwards etc.

Comment: @Mari-LouA There are at least two reasons alt attributes (pedants say tag is the wrong word, but it's easier to type) are useful: 1) when the image is unavailable. and 2) when the screen reader sees it and reads it aloud. For [ngram] charts, it's probably more important that the gist of the graph is in plain text (As you can see, *foo* has a lot more usage than *bar*) and the alt="Google ngram chart".

Comment: @Mari-LouA but the interesting thing is that if the image is already introduced in text as an ngram chart, the alt tag can be blank ("") per the link above. All the description is already in the visible text.

Comment: @SrJoven that depends, users will often say something similar to: *see Ngrams chart*, Ngram agrees with me, etc.

Comment: @Mari-LouA Oh, I don't disagree with what *is*. I'm saying what should be done. That is to say, as *ahem* *cough* *cough* informative as the chart may be, it's probably not as important to casual observer the content as much as the implication. In other words: Yes, it may be *interesting*, but the relevant part is that the chart supports the answer. Not that the chart *is* the answer, which after all should be what's visible text.

Comment: @SrJoven: the problem is that two people can look at the same NGram chart and one of them can decide that it supports the argument, while the other one can decide that it doesn't support the argument. As sighted people, we can look at the chart and make our own conclusions about its validity, but if all a blind user hears is "this is my argument, and here's a chart to support it", then they have no way of knowing if the chart doesn't actually support anything.

Comment: @Marthaª Given that, a) link to the chart source and b) the picture content of NGram is *still* irrelevant to the context. Describing it (invisibly in alt) is only going to be confusing.

Comment: We just started a [similar effort](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/3426/lets-make-mi-yodeya-more-friendly-to-people-and-machines-that-cant-see-images) at Mi Yodeya. We use many fewer images, so we have a shorter hill to climb. Good luck!

Comment: @IsaacMoses  I have been doing some on Mi Yodeya, quite by accident at first. And with all the images of Hebrew text I can't read it has been a challenge.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've made a [Stack Exchange Data Explorer query](http://data.stackexchange.com/english/query/235921/posts-containing-images-without-alt-text?SpecialMention=Ngram) to find posts that lack image descriptions.  As of 2014-10-17, the query shows about 1500 posts that need work.

Please keep in mind that Data Explorer results are based on weekly extracts from the database, and therefore may not reflect recent changes.

Comment: 4753 posts as of 2021-07-09, only 800 or so have 10 UV or higher.

Answer (score 4):

### To do:

(got to page 11 on the Google search)

Thanks to everyone for getting on this so quickly!

### Done:

- [Processor vs Processer](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/158821/processor-vs-processer)
- ["As evidenced by" or "as evident by"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/143022/as-evidenced-by-or-as-evident-by)
- [Use of "entitle" in "the book is entitled 1984"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/102228/using-the-verb-entitle)
- [Etymology of the name "Stimpson"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/108134/etymology-of-the-name-stimpson)
- [What is the difference between "wriggle room" and "wiggle room"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/119293/what-is-the-difference-between-wriggle-room-and-wiggle-room)
- [When Things Used To be "Worth 'X' Millions"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/103446/when-things-used-to-be-worth-x-millions)
- [Who are the witnesses in a court hearing?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/151132/who-are-the-witnesses-in-a-court-hearing)
- [what does it mean: "Lowess smooth"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/150731/what-does-it-mean-lowess-smooth)
- ["All our X" vs. "all of our X"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/65650/all-our-x-vs-all-of-our-x)
- [What is the name of this structure at kids playground?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/75461/what-is-the-name-of-this-structure-at-kids-playground)
- [Why is the word "pepper" used for both capsicum (e.g. bell pepper) and piper (e.g. black pepper)?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/133565/why-is-the-word-pepper-used-for-both-capsicum-e-g-bell-pepper-and-piper-e)
- [How to refer on the property of a line which has a sudden change in its direction?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/138734/how-to-refer-on-the-property-of-a-line-which-has-a-sudden-change-in-its-directio)
- [what's the meaning of "country- years"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/149791/whats-the-meaning-of-country-years)
- [Why are "scaring" and "scarring" confused by some dictionaries?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/75602/why-are-scaring-and-scarring-confused-by-some-dictionaries)
- [Is it "flotation" or "floatation"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/84218/is-it-flotation-or-floatation)
- [Exchanging Experience or Exchange Experience](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/139750/exchanging-experience-or-exchange-experience)
- [How is "all your data are belong to US" grammatically correct?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/62159/how-is-all-your-data-are-belong-to-us-grammatically-correct)
- [How to express the trend in this graph using the appropriate phrases?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/158626/how-to-express-the-trend-in-this-graph-using-the-appropriate-phrases)
- [How to refer to the "elevated areas" of a mountain?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/110492/how-to-refer-to-the-elevated-areas-of-a-mountain)
- [The "a new answer was posted" quick refresh won't update the answer counter properly](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4429/the-a-new-answer-was-posted-quick-refresh-wont-update-the-answer-counter-prop)
- ["I would like to ask you a favour" vs. "I would like to ask you for a favour"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/39971/i-would-like-to-ask-you-a-favour-vs-i-would-like-to-ask-you-for-a-favour)
- [Is "anecdotally" a proper adverb?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/181546/is-anecdotally-a-proper-adverb)
- [How to refer to those fully-equipped houses people let to university students?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/118291/how-to-refer-to-those-fully-equipped-houses-people-let-to-university-students)
- [Why is it called "slippery dick"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/163144/why-is-it-called-slippery-dick)
- [What do we call the GUI "box" which groups elements together?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/44969/what-do-we-call-the-gui-box-which-groups-elements-together)
- ["Book paragraphs" vs "book snippets"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/70975/book-paragraphs-vs-book-snippets)
- [Meaning of "fl." and "seq."](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/185898/meaning-of-fl-and-seq)
- [Meaning of the word "findings"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/113554/meaning-of-the-word-findings)
- [Can Quotation Marks be Used When Describing the Contents of a Label?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/173204/can-quotation-marks-be-used-when-describing-the-contents-of-a-label)
- [What is the meaning of `Position Fulfillment`?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/152970/what-is-the-meaning-of-position-fulfillment)
- [When and how did "pretty" enter English as an intensifying adverb?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/125910/when-and-how-did-pretty-enter-english-as-an-intensifying-adverb)
- [Collective noun for lightning(s) / thunderbolts](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/185672/collective-noun-for-lightnings-thunderbolts)
- [What's a word that describes this facial expression?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/188791/whats-a-word-that-describes-this-facial-expression)
- [Is this a Grill door? how do you narrate if some one opens or closes it?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/147564/is-this-a-grill-door-how-do-you-narrate-if-some-one-opens-or-closes-it)
- [Meaning of 'The difference between involvement and commitment is like ham and eggs. The chicken is involved; the pig is committed'](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/188455/meaning-of-the-difference-between-involvement-and-commitment-is-like-ham-and-eg)
- [Dust vs. Undust?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/189755/dust-vs-undust)
- [Is "kviews" intentional?](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4626/is-kviews-intentional)
- [What's "jewishness" supposed to mean?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/166155/whats-jewishness-supposed-to-mean)
- ["cross this line" versus "cross the line"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/142791/cross-this-line-versus-cross-the-line)
- [Do onomatopoeic words lose their onomatopoeic character?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/170536/do-onomatopoeic-words-lose-their-onomatopoeic-character)
- [Where in the world are cabinets called cupboards?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/167914/where-in-the-world-are-cabinets-called-cupboards)
- [What do you call those fenced grassy areas that people own in the countryside?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/188271/what-do-you-call-those-fenced-grassy-areas-that-people-own-in-the-countryside)
- [What is this part of a bow tie called?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/149449/what-is-this-part-of-a-bow-tie-called)
- [Using 'good' and 'well' in comparisons](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/163955/3559)
- [What does "long" mean before a name?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/174269/what-does-long-mean-before-a-name)
- [Why some blade is called "beaver blade"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/181931/why-some-blade-is-called-beaver-blade)
- [Is the word "radial" in proper usage if I want to describe a star-like structure?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/132245/is-the-word-radial-in-proper-usage-if-i-want-to-describe-a-star-like-structure)
- [A word that refers to a "half-smile"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/117586/a-word-that-refers-to-a-half-smile)
- [Romney claims that China likes to "flaunt the rules"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/47977/romney-claims-that-china-likes-to-flaunt-the-rules)
- [What is the proper name for the corkscrew at the top of a soda bottle?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/119256/what-is-the-proper-name-for-the-corkscrew-at-the-top-of-a-soda-bottle)
- [Put down a downpayment](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/171808/3559)
- [The meaning of "muted kinetics"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/193149/the-meaning-of-muted-kinetics)
- [English equivalent of komorebi (木漏れ日) — "sunshine filtering through leaves"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/181055/english-equivalent-of-komorebi-%e6%9c%a8%e6%bc%8f%e3%82%8c%e6%97%a5-sunshine-filtering-through-leaves)
- [Synonym for the tag "adverb-position"](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5231/synonym-for-the-tag-adverb-position)
- [Why does the word "tortilla" refer to three distinct types of edibles?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/190291/why-does-the-word-tortilla-refer-to-three-distinct-types-of-edibles)
- [Etymology of "manhole"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/171125/etymology-of-manhole)
- [Momentary vs Temporary](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/193520/momentary-vs-temporary)
- [What is the meaning and usage of this “is true of”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/198326/what-is-the-meaning-and-usage-of-this-is-true-of)
- [Etymology of "bridge" (the card game)](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/172810/etymology-of-bridge-the-card-game)
- [The name given to the trail of afterburn (of a jet perhaps?)](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/157925/the-name-given-to-the-trail-of-afterburn-of-a-jet-perhaps)
- [Why 'mention graph' of genuflect is so steep?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/163189/why-mention-graph-of-genuflect-is-so-steep)
- [What is the origin and sense of the phrase “put up or shut up”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/198682/what-is-the-origin-and-sense-of-the-phrase-put-up-or-shut-up)
- [turn right backward or turn slightly right backward?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/190057/turn-right-backward-or-turn-slightly-right-backward)
- [word for getting hit in the head, lowering your neck and raising your shoulder? (shrug?)](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/200063/word-for-getting-hit-in-the-head-lowering-your-neck-and-raising-your-shoulder)
- [Is there a generic expression for a "universal product"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/200170/is-there-a-generic-expression-for-a-universal-product)
- [What do you call a blanket used for moving?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/193143/what-do-you-call-a-blanket-used-for-moving)
- [What do you call those roofs you usually find at the entrance of buildings?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/200149/what-do-you-call-those-roofs-you-usually-find-at-the-entrance-of-buildings)
- [Word for a body of water that is sufficiently populated with fish and worthy of fishing in](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/196354/word-for-a-body-of-water-that-is-sufficiently-populated-with-fish-and-worthy-of)
- [Word for "the entire back part of the body"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/200950/word-for-the-entire-back-part-of-the-body)
- [A single word for a building located in the centre of fork (intersection)?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/175301/a-single-word-for-a-building-located-in-the-centre-of-fork-intersection)
- [What is the meaning of the (seemingly) noun word "claw-catch" in a poem?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/200555/what-is-the-meaning-of-the-seemingly-noun-word-claw-catch-in-a-poem)
- [Prepositions: "The confusing widgets of language"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/195036/prepositions-the-confusing-widgets-of-language)
- [What's the proper American English and British English word for the wind shield used on beaches?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/194128/whats-the-proper-american-english-and-british-english-word-for-the-wind-shield)
- [what do you call a water tap placed on the outside](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/190089/what-do-you-call-a-water-tap-placed-on-the-outside)
- [Present perfect continuous](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/197804/present-perfect-continuous)
- [order of adjectives exceptions](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/196856/order-of-adjectives-exceptions)
- [What is the name of the symbol used to depict 'eat and drink'?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/198561/what-is-the-name-of-the-symbol-used-to-depict-eat-and-drink)
- [What would be an apt technical term for the fear of eating cat food?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/196830/what-would-be-an-apt-technical-term-for-the-fear-of-eating-cat-food)
- [What do you call the protruding square structures on the top of a tower?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/199029/what-do-you-call-the-protruding-square-structures-on-the-top-of-a-tower)
- [What is the name of the supports which are used with screws to hold a box together?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/174528/what-is-the-name-of-the-supports-which-are-used-with-screws-to-hold-a-box-togeth)
- ["I'm flabbergasted!" - Old fashioned? Pedantic? Refined? Educated?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/196942/im-flabbergasted-old-fashioned-pedantic-refined-educated)
- [What is the meaning of this “General Government”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/198332/what-is-the-meaning-of-this-general-government)
- [Use of the opening roll for corny/pointless exposition?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/196492/use-of-the-opening-roll-for-corny-pointless-exposition)
- ["Two yellow spots on its wings" vs "a yellow spot on both wings"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/149533/two-yellow-spots-on-its-wings-vs-a-yellow-spot-on-both-wings)
- [If X was not part Y, I'd like it - meaning](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/189891/if-x-was-not-part-y-id-like-it-meaning)
- [Translation of German "Bolzplatz" – what's the name for an outdoor area whose purpose is to provide room for soccer/football?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/184445/translation-of-german-bolzplatz-whats-the-name-for-an-outdoor-area-whose-pu)
- [What are "schlieren" in English?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/190287/what-are-schlieren-in-english)
- [What is the meaning of "sticks" as a measurement unit?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/195586/what-is-the-meaning-of-sticks-as-a-measurement-unit)
- [What does "mechanical" mean here?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/97714/what-does-mechanical-mean-here)
- [A ligature "og"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/125887/a-ligature-og)
- [What do you call the individual enclosed defecating areas in toilets?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/143627/what-do-you-call-the-individual-enclosed-defecating-areas-in-toilets)
- [Where were "should", "shall", and "must" in the 18th Century?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/39751/where-were-should-shall-and-must-in-the-18th-century)
- [How do the tenses and aspects in English correspond temporally to one another?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/21846/how-do-the-tenses-and-aspects-in-english-correspond-temporally-to-one-another/21847#21847)
- [What do you call unclean water that you can't see through?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/147511/what-do-you-call-unclean-water-that-you-cant-see-through/147515#147515)

Comment: did "what does it mean"

Comment: Thanks, Ludwik!

Comment: Argh, I hate doing nGrams graphs!

Comment: @Mitch: I'm right there with you. I find myself wondering if I can just summarily delete graphs that aren't absolutely vital to the question/answer. I'm also growing to detest screen captures and pictures of old newspapers and other images of text. :/

Comment: @Marthaª wouldn't the solution be "newspaper clipping illustrating how (word) is relevant/related to answer" There has to be a summary of some sorts.

Comment: What, that's it?

Answer (score 3):

The value of doing this is highlighted by today's Imgur downtime. We have questions like "[A pronunciation question of slough](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/374768/a-pronunciation-question-of-slough)" which make no sense without the embedded image.

This is a problem for sighted users today, and it's a problem for blind users all of the time.

Comment: Ah, so that's what's going on. I thought my new PC had some issues.

Comment: Yeah, but what's the alternative? Type out the dozen+ "ough" words in the alt-text? That defeats the purpose of using an image in the first place. For that example, I think the best we can expect people to tag is "Series of words containing the string "ough" having very different pronunciations".

Comment: @DanBron The unintended consequence of using an image is to make the site useleess for the blind. In this case, the image contained text. So yes the obvious alternative was to type out the text.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something. How does a blind person read the alt-texts (or even anything on a computer screen)? Text-to-speech plugins?

Comment: @NVZ Text to speech is most common. Some use a Braille module.

Comment: @DanBron what was the purpose of having it be an image in the first place?  a little chunk of text formatted with markdown could have replaced it.

Comment: @Hellion The original author of the image clearly created it so that all the "ough"s would line up vertically, making the cognitive dissonance in their different pronunciations even sharper. The OP who used it in the post did so because it offered a simple, direct, and low-effort way to illustrate the variability of English orthography (or pronunciation, depending on how you look at it). Asking that person to then *type out the whole image* defeats that entire purpose, and therefore makes barriers to entry higher, and therefore reduces the likelihood of getting (quality) posts.

Answer (score 2):

> You don't have to write Shakespeare or Nabokov...

That's reassuring. So, it's not necessary to be one the greatest playwrights ever known to mankind or probably the most iconic 20th century novelist to fill in the image description. Good to know!

But according to an edit of yours, where the image is a photo I took of the Irish Daily Mail, the description has to be pretty detailed.

> Issue of the Irish Daily Mail from Monday, June 30, 2014, folded in
>   half. Banner image has three columns, first is a picture of a woman,
>   second is the text "Miriam: I've gotten better looking as I get older
>   see page nine", third is the text "only €1 a big read for a small
>   price". The third's background is a baby blue circle. The whole banner
>   image has a gradient background going from red to black. Below the
>   banner image is a by line: Accidents, fires and breakdowns mean
>   vehicles 'not fit for purpose'. The main headline is below the fold.]

I mean I love the description, don't get me wrong. It's beautifully crafted, I wouldn't be surprised if Google picks up on it, but it does seem a little excessive.

From now on are we expected to go into so much detail? For heaven's sake *why*?

Comment: People go into as much detail as they think necessary.

Comment: @MattЭллен Could you explain its relevance? I'm no computer geek, it must be obvious to programmers but on me it's lost.

Comment: The description becomes what is known as the "alt text" of the image. This is useful for people using text only browsers and for people who use a screen reader. Mostly, it's to help blind people (they are the major group who use screen readers). A screen reader is a web browser that reads the contents of the screen out loud.

Comment: Oh. Presumably it's a machine that reads text out aloud. And if that's the case, surely the aim of the description is to pinpoint the focus? *Headline title "bla bla" with a photo of a blonde middle-aged TV presenter called Miriam. The picture shows the reader that the attractive woman in question is not in her 30s (or 40s)*. Whereas saying the paper is folded in half, it has three columns, a *blue* circle, a gradient *red* to *black*,  and quoting the second headline is, I think, distracting for a blind person, there's an overload of information which all appears to carry equal importance.

Comment: This should be a separate question, not a question masquerading as an answer.

Comment: If the image can be described adequately by text, shouldn't it just be replaced altogether?

Comment: @Marthaª I was asking for clarification, I wasn't aware that  Matt Эллен was asking a question. My post is clearly asking *why*, I'm not acting sneeky in the slightest. Tsk!

Comment: @Barmar I think images can save a great deal of time and space. Somehow when you actually see a ship sinking, it becomes more believable, more real. Likewise the image of a  newspaper headline stops anyone from doubting that you invented, or incorrectly transcribed the whole thing.

Comment: @Mari-LouA "Images can save a great deal of time" Not if we're doing descriptions that accurately cover what's in the image + uploading the image, compared to just writing the description. "a newspaper headline stops anyone from doubting that you invented, or incorrectly transcribed the whole thing". A citation can do that too. It's also worth remembering we live a Photoshop age. "I think images can save a great deal of time and space" Text typically requires smaller data storage, and therefore makes it cheaper for SE to provide. However I agree images make it more real.

Comment: @Mari-LouA please feel free to edit any of the descriptions you want to improve. I'm far from perfect at describing things!

Comment: Alt text should be minimal (and I'm guilty of not following this. See my comment on the master post). Note that screen readers read aloud everything on the screen. If the relevance of the image is described in public facing text, the content of the image should not replicate that information.